# Command line to create 7z archive of two folders and a file to self-extract to specified location

Tags: compression, archive, 7zip

I'm new to 7zip, but what command line do I need to create a self-extracting exe which will extract files to a specific location and run a specific command file.

I need it to be silent, the user just double-clicks the exe and it recreates the folder structure and runs the command and exits.

Source folder structure:

```
C:\Source\mycmd.bat
C:\Source\A\lots of files
C:\Source\B\lots more files
```

Command to create C:\MYEXE.EXE:

```
7z.exe <WHAT GOES HERE!!!>
```

After running MYEXE.EXE on the target machine, the following file/folder structure is created:

```
C:\Dest
C:\Dest\mycmd.bat
C:\Dest\A\lots of files
C:\Dest\B\lots more files
```

Then C:\Dest\mycmd.bat is run and exits when complete

All with no user input after double-clicking MYEXE.EXE on the target machine.

Can it be done???

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Create a 7z file containing the files to extract (including the one to run), e.g.

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%TEMP%\MyArchive.7z" -mmt -mx5 "FileToRun.cmd" "FolderForArchive1" "FolderForArchive2"
   ```
2. Create a config folder to indicate the display name and file to run, e.g.

   ```
   ;!@Install@!UTF-8!
   Title="MySelfExtractingArchive"
   ExecuteFile="FileToRun.cmd"
   ;!@InstallEnd@!
   ```
3. Append the files with a sfx header (from 7-Zip website), e.g.

   ```
   copy /b "7zS.sfx" + "MyConfig.cfg" + "%TEMP%\MyArchive.7z" "MySelfExtractor.exe"
   ```